# Eclipse debugging issue

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm debugging a Java aplication in eclipse. The problem is that now(I don't know what I've done) the debug starts from the beginning(the first line of the main) and not from the first breakpoint. It's very annoying because I have to go through many lines to get to the part that I want.

Comment: What is exactly your problem? What do you mean "starts from the beginning" ?

Comment: sorry, starts from the first line of the main, I'll edit

Comment: For starters, click "Resume" not "Step".

Comment: Note that you can tell it to continue to the next breakpoint with F8. Ctrl-R allows you to continue to a given line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the debug configuration for the configuration you are launching on the Main tab and make sure that "Stop in main" is *NOT* checked.

1. Right-click on the project in the Package Explorer tab
2. Choose "Debug As " > "Debug Configurations ..."
3. Down the left side, find and select the debug configuration for the project/app/main you are debugging.
4. Click on the "Main" tab.
5. Uncheck "Stop in main"
6. Click "Apply" button

Answer (score 0):

You've probably have edited the file while debugging and the lines don't correspond to what you see. Try save the file, refreshing your project on the package explorer and try again. Also check that you are not escaping the breakpoints. If nothing works try removing your breakpoints and replacing them or even restart eclipse.